# Trigger SVG Animation Only When in View

Tags: jquery, svg, scroll

I'm having an issue with an SVG animation on one of my pages.  I have other traditional animations (gifs) that trigger properly when scrolling but my SVG animation only works properly when scrolling down the page. When scrolling back up, it's triggering too soon, and when the element is not visible on the screen yet, despite the code stating to only run when in view.

I'm using jQuery Visible to trigger the animation.

Here is the relevant jQuery.

```
     if (jQuery("#checks").visible() == true) {     
   jQuery('#checks li').each(function(index) {
     jQuery(this).delay(1000*index).queue(function() {  
     if (jQuery('.wrapper', this).html() == "") {   
       jQuery('.wrapper', this).html('<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 98.5 98.5" enable-background="new 0 0 98.5 98.5" xml:space="preserve"><path class="checkmark" fill="none" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M81.7,17.8C73.5,9.3,62,4,49.2,4C24.3,4,4,24.3,4,49.2s20.3,45.2,45.2,45.2s45.2-20.3,45.2-45.2c0-8.6-2.4-16.6-6.5-23.4l0,0L45.6,68.2L24.7,47.3"/></svg>');
     }
       jQuery(this).dequeue();
     });
    });
 } 

  if (jQuery("#checks").visible(true) == false) {   
   jQuery("#checks li .wrapper").html('');
 }
```

Comment: To clarify: this is all wrapped in a $(document).scroll() right? Also it may help if you show the code for .visible() (I'm assuming this is custom extension you wrote instead of just doing .is(':visible'))

Comment: Yes, it is wrapped in a scroll function. I'm using a custom plugin that I did not write for the visible portion: https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible

Comment: Try using .is(':visible') instead of .visible() to rule out the plugin being the issue.